# What is the correct way to fully remove a control from a parent control/form?

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, dispose, destroy

I have a UI element in my application where a Panel is used to host one of several potential custom UserControls. The Panel itself is hosted in a standardised UserControl that I am using something like a non-modal dialog that I'm calling a 'pane'.

The method I use is to instantiate a new instance of the standard pane, then with logic instantiate one of the several optional hosted controls inside it using `Panel.Controls.Add(control)`. I then add the new pane to the interface control in a set location, again with a `Control.Controls.Add(control)`, followed by a `control.BringToFront()` to maximise its z position.

This all works well, however when the time comes to hide the pane and destroy it, I cannot seem to fully get rid of it. Originally I was simply using `Control.Controls.Remove(control)` and for good measure setting the pane's Parent property to Nothing. This would have the desired effect of making the pane disappear, and my assumption was that now the control was unreferenced, that GC would dispose of it.

What I am seeing however is that the control still blits instantaneously onto the screen when the next outer hosting TabControl changes tab page, implying it still exists somewhere. I can confirm that this is not a graphical issue and the pane object persists using the VS Watch window's 'Make Object ID'. (At least I think this is proof, that without a code-accessible reference I can still directly see the object and its properties continue to exist.)

I have tried replacing

```
Control.Controls.Remove(pane)
pane.Parent = Nothing
```

with

```
pane.Dispose()
GC.Collect()
```

where the Dispose call I can confirm both removes the control from its parent's Controls collection and sets its Parent property to Nothing, but appears to do no more. It persists after forced GC and still blits onscreen occasionally.

This all leads to my original question, what is the proper way to remove and fully destroy controls after they have served their purpose?

Comment: Are you sure the `pane.Dispose()` method is not leaving anything behind? An `EventHandler` perhaps? Some `SqlConnection` open? Something...

Comment: This might lead to another question, I know using 'AddHandler's will leave behind some mess if not managed correctly, is there ever a case where the 'WithEvents' and 'Handles' keywords may introduce the same mess?

Comment: I have the same question, I'd like to see that question answered myself...

Comment: The first snippet is definitely wrong, the panel leaks forever.  The 2nd snippet is definitely right, minus the Collect call.  Any events that you subscribed in the panel code for event sources that are not the panel or its children have to be unsubscribed manually.

Comment: Having reviewed all of the descendent code, I have not implemented any 'AddHandler' methods, all events are working through the WithEvents and Handles keywords, which I expect, at least in most normal cases, to unsubscribe themselves automatically. I suppose there must be a spurious reference somewhere, just haven't got a good tool to find it with.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720161%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) article from MSDN it seems like you might be experiencing side affects from the object being on the finalization queue.

> A Dispose method should call the GC.SuppressFinalize method for the object it is disposing. If the object is currently on the finalization queue, GC.SuppressFinalize prevents its Finalize method from being called.

Translation: The finalize method isn't being called, and so the resources associated with your control are not being released. After a bit more digging, I found that you should

> Always call Dispose before you release your last reference to the Component. Otherwise, the resources it is using will not be freed until the garbage collector calls the Component object's Finalize method.

From [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cc9y48w.aspx) article.

So either you need to release your last reference OR you need to call the components finalize method directly so your GC.Collect() will work.